# Unexpected behavior of Array.prototype.splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

While implementing an internal `EventEmitter` for a project I was working on, I came across a strange quirk when using `Array.prototype.splice` inside a `for... in` loop. The function does not successfully remove the indeces from the array within the loop:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index;

for (index in array) {
    if (index === 2) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }

    console.log(array[index]);
}

console.log(array);
```

Running on Google Chrome version 43, this outputs

```
1
2
3
4
5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

when I'm expecting something like

```
1
2
4
5
undefined†
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Is this by design or a bug? I cannot find any documented reference to this behavior.

**†** Possibly, if length is not calculated during each iteration of `for... in` implementation

Comment: fyi: for-in with arrays is frowned upon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: @jamesemanon thanks for the observation. My question wasn't implying that I thought it was acceptable, but with the body of the loop written the way I have it, my `Array.prototype.slice` worked within a `for(;;)` loop, but not within a `for... in` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.  :)

In Javascript, Arrays are Objects, which means that Array indices are Object keys.  And in Javascript, Object keys are strings.

So your condition `index === 2` is always going to be false, because the number 2 is not the same as the string '2'.

One solution would be to continue to use the identity operator (recommended by most) and compare `index` to the string value '2'

```
index === '2'
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the equality operator which will typecast the comparison (although this will likely get you into trouble at some point)...

```
index == 2
```

but works just fine in your case.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb for not catching that, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I think we've all gotten bitten by that one  :)