# Creating particular loop behavior

Tags: javascript, event-handling, iteration, eventemitter

While creating an internal `EventEmitter` for my project, I became curious how to produce a particular loop iteration behavior for attached event handlers. Here's a demonstration of my concern:

```
MyEventEmitter.prototype.emit = function (name, event) {
    var index;

    if (name in this.events) {
        for (index = 0; index < this.events[name].length; index++) {
            this.events[name][index].call(this, event);
        }
    }
};
```

To clarify, `this.events` is an object with each key being an event name and each value being an array of event handlers to be called for the respective event.

However, as I observed with [Unexpected behavior of Array.prototype.splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096066), this would fail for event handlers attached with `MyEventEmitter.prototype.once` because the wrapper event handler function would remove itself, causing the iteration to skip the event handlers within the indeces of the array immediately after the one-time event handlers in the array. Here's what I mean:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], index;

for (index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    // log event handlers that get called
    console.log(array[index]);
    // let's assume that `3` is like an event handler that removes itself
    if (array[index] === 3) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

This would log the following:

```
1
2
3
5
```

Note that `4` does not get iterated because `3` removes itself. How would I write `emit` to accomodate this? Or, if appropriate, how do native implementations of `EventEmitter`s handle this?

Comment: @jooko thanks, forgot to add that tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the node source myself, I found [their solution in events.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/events.js#L128):

```
listeners = handler.slice();
```

Basically, it makes a copy of the listeners array to iterate over so that if a listener deletes itself from the original array, the copy's indeces remain unaffected.